# Adding an image to list view vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a list view with fixed and dynamic items. I intend to print it as a receipt for payment validation

This is how I am adding the fixed items

```
Dim ListItem As ListViewItem
ListItem = ListView1.Items.Add("ST PAUL'S SECONDARY SCHOOL")
Dim logo As ListViewItem
logo = ListView1.Items.Add(Image.FromFile("1.png"))
```

My problem is that the line for adding the image is giving me the following error

> Error  BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' can be called with these arguments: 'Public Overridable Overloads Function Add(text As String) As ListViewItem': Value of type 'Image' cannot be converted to 'String'. 'Public Overridable Overloads Function Add(value As ListViewItem) As ListViewItem': Value of type 'Image' cannot be converted to 'ListViewItem'. SchoolManager C:\Users\MASENO\Source\Repos\SchoolManager\SchoolManager\Pay Fees.vb  18  Active

I have tried this code to add the image from resources but it is not adding any image and displaying no error

```
      Dim il = New ImageList()
    il.Images.Add("1", My.Resources.barlogo)
    ListView1.LargeImageList = il
    ListItem.ImageKey = "1"
```

What could I be doing wrong and how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

Use an [ImageList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist?view=netframework-4.7.2) to hold your image, then apply it to the ListView by key.

```
' your code
Dim ListItem As ListViewItem
ListItem = ListView1.Items.Add("ST PAUL'S SECONDARY SCHOOL")
' new code
Dim il = new ImageList()
il.Images.Add("1", Image.FromFile("1.png"))
ListView1.LargeImageList = il
ListItem.ImageKey = "1"
```

Comment: I have modified your solution to use the resource like this  ```Dim il = New ImageList()
        il.Images.Add("1", My.Resources.barlogo)
        ListView1.LargeImageList = il
        ListItem.ImageKey = "1"``` But it is not adding any image or displaying any error